# How should I write out the unit testing if statement for this if statement for these query params?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, if-statement, query-string

.ts file:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    if (
      this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.has('esign') && 
      this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.has('registration')
    ) {
      this.eSignAndRegistration = true;
    }
```

.spec.ts file:

```
  let esign_registration = false;
  const mockActivatedRoute = {
    snapshot: {
      queryParamMap: {
        has: (response) => {
          if (response == 'esign' && response == 'registration') {
            return esign_registration;
          }
```

test:

```
  fit("should show the 1st mat-card if the param is 'esign&registration'", () => {
    esign_registration = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.nativeElement;
    expect(component.eSignAndRegistration).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

The error keeps coming as "Expected undefined to be truthy." How does the 'has' if statement need to be written to get the unit test to work? I have tried

```
if (response == 'esign' && 'registration')
```

and

```
if (response == 'esign&registration')
```

and whole variety of other methods, but they all kept giving the same error.

Comment: Not really answering your question but you should use tools to ease mocking the routes parameters rather than creating a whole mock by yourself. Spectator library can help. I believe recent versions of Angulzr even have some stuff built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response == 'esign' && response == 'registration'`

Try changing `&&` to `||`. If response is a string it can only be one of those.

Comment: So that helped fix that test case, but it gave 'esign' and 'registration' that problem.                                            
snapshot: {
      queryParamMap: {
        has: (response) => {
          if (response == 'esign' || response == 'registration') {
            return esign_registration;
          }
          if (response == 'registration') {
            return registration;
          }
          if (response == 'esign') {
            return esign;
          }
          if (response == 'css') {
            return css;
          }
        },
      },

Comment: Now it depends on what you want to do. I guess you want separate ``if`` statements for esign & for registration? Then remove the first if statement (don't know what it's for), and assign ``esign = true`` and ``registration = true`` in your test.